# How to properly redirect StdIn/StdOut to control VLC?

Tags: c#, redirect, process, vlc

I´m writing a platform independend C# Application (My targets are Windows and Raspbian). I want to use VLC for Audio Playback.

I tried to start VLC using the remote control interface `vlc -I rc` and redirecting StdIn/StdOut that I can send commands and receive information of the VLC process:

```
vlcproc = new Process();
vlcproc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(VLCPath, "-I rc");
vlcproc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
vlcproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
vlcproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
bool res = vlcproc.Start();
vlcproc.OutputDataReceived += vlcproc_OutputDataReceived;
```

But it does not work as expected. VLC seems not to get anything if I write some commands using `vlcproc.StandardInput.WriteLine()`. I tried to use `add ...` on local files and streams. Using C#, no playback - entered manually, playback. I do not get any StdOut information as well (printed by `Console.Write()` in the Event Handler).

What I´m doing wrong?

PS: A reliable, cross-plattform audio/video-player that supports files as wells as network-streams and can be integrated in a Mono/.NET-supported GUI Framework would be even better than this attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that VLC doesn't act on stdout/stin. I was able to solve the stdout problem by running it through `script -c "<vlc command with parameters>"`.